# Error with connect in react-redux?

Tags: javascript, mobile, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am getting this error in my react-native/redux app, although I believe I have already wrapped the root component in a `<Provider>`:

"Could not find 'store' in either the context or props of 'Connect(FirstView)'. Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`, or explicitly pass 'store' as a prop to Connect(PropertyView)."

I am wrapping the root component in a Provider in containers/root.js:

```
class Root extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                {() => <SearchPage />}
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default Root;
```

And then SearchPage transitions to SearchResults via NavigatorIOS, and SearchResults transitions to PropertyView via a NavigatorIOS:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
        title: "Property",
        component: PropertyView,
        passProps: {property: property,
                    addToSaved: addToSaved
                    }

    });
```

I can't figure out what else I am missing to cause this error. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a connected component?

```
// SearchPage.js
import { connect } from 'redux'

const SearchPage = React.createClass({
...
})

export default connect()(SearchPage)
```

This is just something to try... hope it helps.